# Scala: lazy evaluation on a Collection (Strategy Pattern)

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I have a construct of this sort:

```
if(condition1)
  lengthyOperation1
else if(condition2)
  lengthyOperation2
else if(condition3)
  lengthyOperation3
...
else
  lastLengthyOperation
```

I want to express in about the following way:

```
lazy val seq = Seq(
  condition1 -> lengthyOperation1,
  condition2 -> lengthyOperation2,
  condition3 -> lengthyOperation3,
  ...
  true -> lastLengthyOperation
)

seq.find(_._1).match { case(_, v) => v }
```

The problem is that the evaluation of the last line executes all lengthy operations when it gets to "seq". How do I make it so the lengthy operations execute only if needed?

Note: the conditions are not possible pattern matchings of the same expression (i.e. I cannot use a single match statement for this)

Edit: should I use a Stream for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean `Seq`, not `Map`.

You could use `Seq` instead of `if` sequence here, though I don't think its readable.

You should use `getOrElse` after `find`. Assuming each `lengthyOperationN` is a function:

```
seq.find(_._1).map{_._2}.getOrElse(lastLengthyOperation).apply()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that you have laziness in the wrong spot. When you declare

```
lazy val seq = Seq(
  condition1 -> lengthyOperation1,
  ...
)
```

then once you touch `seq`, the whole sequence is evaluated with all its lengthy operations, no matter which of them you touch. Sequence is strict in its elements.

You can do what you want using `Stream`s, but I guess it's easier to do it using `Option`s, which are designed for this purpose. Let's just declare a helper implicit function on options. If it's called on `Some`, it doesn't do anything. If it's called on `None`, it checks a condition and if it's satisfied, returns `Some(result)`:

```
implicit class IfOption[A](opt: Option[A]) {
  def ?>[B >: A](condition: Boolean, result: => B): Option[B] =
    opt.orElse(if (condition) Some(result) else None);
}
```

Now we can do things like

```
println(
    None
      ?> (1 != 1, "A")
      ?> (2 == 2, "B")
      ?> (3 == 2, "C")
)
```

where the type of the printed expression is `Option[String]` and prints `Some(B)`, or

```
println(
    None
      ?> (1 != 1, "Yes")
      ?> (2 != 2, "No")
      ?> (3 != 2, "heck")
      getOrElse ("ah")
)
```

where the type is just "String".